# SQL Server 2008 - Email notifications

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL server / database locally and accessed through ip etc...

What I want to know is how to send emails directly from the server (when n happens)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Database Mail`.  To send e-mails via SQL Server you can use the following stored procedure:

`sp_send_dbmail`

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',
@recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
@body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',
@subject = 'Automated Success Message' ;
```

Or how to configure a `SQL agent to send mail`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186358.aspx

*Additional references*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177580.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/) explains how to set everything up

And then you would need to write a trigger for when N happens to send an email